# Should Non-Copyable class have user conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, lvalue, noncopyable

My question is, should non-copyable objects have implicit/explicit user conversion? At least from my example below, conversions look very much like copies.

PS: I know that is recomended here to "Avoid implicit conversion operators" https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c164-avoid-implicit-conversion-operators

To explain my rationale suppose that I have a class that manages OS objects using RAII. Nothing fancy.

```
struct unique_handle
{
    unique_handle(HANDLE h) : handle(h) {}

    //NON COPYABLE
    unique_handle(const unique_handle&) = delete;
    unique_handle& operator=(const unique_handle&) = delete;

    //MOVEABLE
    unique_handle(unique_handle&& other) : handle(other.handle)
    {
        other.handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }   
    unique_handle& operator=(unique_handle&& other)
    {
        if (this != &other) {
            handle = other.handle;
            other.handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~unique_handle()
    {
        if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ::CloseHandle(handle);
    }
private:
    HANDLE handle;
}
```

Which is OK. It allows me to do something like:

```
namespace w32
{
    unique_handle CreateFile(...)       
    {
        HANDLE handle = ::CreateFileA(...);
        return { handle };
    }
}
```

The problem is that other OS functions will not accept my object. So I tried the, always dangerous, path of implicit/explicit user conversions.

```
struct unique_handle
{
...
    operator HANDLE() const noexcept { return handle; }
...
}
```

Which allows me to use my object normally.

```
...
auto dirHandle = w32::CreateFile(...); // my function returning my object
::ReadDirectoryChangesW(dirHandle, // my object on a native OS call
        ...);
...
```

Which is wonderful! But the problem now is that I allowed the possibility of leaking a closed handle. Suppose that I directly assign my object, never lvalue-ing it, to a HANDLE object, leaking not only the unmanaged HANDLE but even leaking a closed HANDLE. For example:

```
Problem 1
...
HANDLE h = w32::CreateFile(...);
...
```

I understand that the following happened on problem 1:

1 - I got the HANDLE from the OS and passed it to my object to managed it;
2 - I returned the HANDLE using the implicit user conversion operator;
3 - the compiler called my object destructor that closed the handle;
4 - a closed HANDLE has leaked in a non-obvious manner. Possible runtime error. Not even an error check is going to catch this because the HANDLE is not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Off course that I have also enabled this case. But for arguments sake, let us say that I accept this case.

```
Problem 2
HANDLE h1 = ...;
{
    auto h2 = w32::CreateFile(...); // my method and my object
    h1 = h2;                        // implicit cast to the OS HANDLE
}                                   // our favorite feature closing the HANDLE
::ReadDirectoryChangesW(h1, ...);
...
```

Because if, instead of opting for implicit/explicit user conversion, I opted for an unary operator, I could have avoided conversions from the temporary objects doing something like:

```
HANDLE operator !(unique_handle& v2)
{
    return v2.handle;
}
```

Which gives me a compilation error on lines such as:

```
...
HANDLE h = !w32::CreateFile(...);
...
```

Which is ideal, but as far I know we cannot do the same with conversions.

Other solutions that I imagine are functions such as:

```
struct unique_handle
{
    ...
    // just return - In my opinion also a copy, but what can we make?
    [[nodiscard]] HANDLE get() const noexcept { return handle; } 

    // Stop managing this HANDLE
    [[nodiscard]] HANDLE release() noexcept
    {
        auto h = handle;
        handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        return h;
    }
    ...
}
```

So going back to my question, is this scenario avoidable? Or Non-Copyable objects should never have user conversion? And to be honest, how are they different from a simple get() that returns some managed private object?
Maybe a way to avoid user conversions from temporary objects? Can we force a object to be lvalue-ed before any other use, be it a method call or a conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this scenario avoidable?

No. The library functions you're using do not, cannot and will not ever support your smart resource management. That's a shame, particularly as they do not provide any of their own, but it is the reality of the situation.

> Or Non-Copyable objects should never have user conversion? And to be honest, how are they different from a simple get() that returns some managed private object?

`.get()` is a bigger warning flag to the reader that care must be taken regarding the lifetime of the resource being extracted in a "raw" fashion. Your implicit conversions are quicker and shorter to write, but do not signal this and are more likely to cause bugs.

> Maybe a way to avoid user conversions from temporary objects? Can we force a object to be lvalue-ed before any other use, be it a method call or a conversion?

Yes, a member function can have [ref-qualifiers](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/). Although, as above, I don't think this really solves your overarching problem, which is that *every* use of these library functions will require careful observation by the reader, no matter what design you come up with.

Look at `std::unique_ptr`. It has a `get()` function (to support third party functions that *demand* a `T*`) and no implicit conversions to anything (to prevent this from happening by accident).

My general advice is to avoid implicit conversions where you can help it.

Comment: Ref-Qualifiers definitely did it. I tried two approaches here:

operator HANDLE () & { return handle; }
operator HANDLE () && { return release(); }

and

[[nodiscard]] HANDLE get() & { ... }
[[nodiscard]] HANDLE release() { ... }

If they are good paths or not, is something to think...